# I want to generate job serial no in client side click. please help if there is any suggest

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

Here I want to create `JOBNO` for my application for each order. Every order has different customer, quote no, address…etc.

```
JOBNO=       MUM    XXXX    01    1415
```

First 3digit = coming from port code data table (I already created table field).

Next 4digit = serial no (ex:0001);which is auto generated one by one .

Next 2digit assumed   as current month .Every month start the serial no. has to begin with origin no(0001) and again ends in end of the month.

Next 2digit=current month

Last 4digits=financial year (ex2014:2015) last two digits (1415).

Condition:
    When I choose the port name from dropdown list like before code is auto generated and place it to the JOBNO textbox.

Comment: did you try anything ? can you put your effort here ?

Answer (score 0):

you can move ahead something like this and ask where struck,

```
   Declare @JOBNO varchar(20)
--       MUM    XXXX    01    1415
Declare @portcode char(3)='MUM' --from db
Declare @CurMonth char(2)= subSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6),getdate(), 112),5,2)
Declare @maxid int=1 -- from db (it should be int only
--select @CurMonth
Declare @FinYear char(4)= substring(cast((year(getdate())-1) as varchar(4)),3,2)
                            +substring(cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)),3,2)
--select @FinYear
--Select RIGHT('000' + CAST(@maxid AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
--finally,
Select @portcode+ @CurMonth+ RIGHT('000' + CAST(@maxid AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)+@FinYear
```